# Change default terminal to tilix terminal using shortcut

Tags: gnome-terminal, update-alternatives

On Ubuntu whenever I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, it will open the default terminal of Ubuntu. Now I want this shortcut to open my tilix terminal. How can I do this?

Comment: Hey Muhammad Iftikhar! I hope this website (https://itsfoss.com/change-default-terminal-ubuntu/) will help you.

Answer (score 14):

You can change your default terminal application via `update-alternatives`. The following is how you do it.

1. Open your current terminal.
2. Run this command, `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`
3. It will show several terminal applications that are installed on your system. Type the number corresponding to Tilix. Press Enter.

Now you can try to press `CTRL+ALT+T` and Tilix should show up.

I hope this helps.

Comment: yes its helped me alot Thank you!

Comment: @MuhammadIftikhar You can mark this answer as the accepted answer if this helps. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this anwser ! This should be marked as the accepted answer.